# Only test/build commits on the develop branch - CircleCI

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci

I am trying to set up CircleCI for my AngularJS project. I think I've done everything correctly, but there are some problems.

1. When a commit is pushed on a feature branch (anything except develop or master), I don't want to run test, and definitely not create a build.
2. When a PR is created to the develop branch, I want this PR to be tested.
3. When that PR is merged, or if other direct commits are made on the develop branch, I want a new build to be created & deployed.

The problem is that first point, at this moment every commit on any branch will trigger a test, which is just not needed at all.

I've tried this in circle.yml but that also stops PR's to the develop branch from being tested it seems:

```
general:
  branches:
    only:
      - develop
```

So how can I get Circle to behave in the way that I want? Or should I remove that config above and let it test every commit on every branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a PR is made in github the commits that form the pull request still are a part of their original branches and not the new branch that means any tests that Circle will do will happen as part of the original branch which you are implicitly blacklisting. PRs that are merged should definitely trigger new builds since the merged PR results in a new commit SHA and triggers CircleCI. If you want tests to run when you make a PR you will need to change the circle.yml file to allow the branch you're making the PR from.

An alternate way to get this behavior would be to use regex matching in your branch whitelisting so that any branch name starting with something like `pr-` would be built normally and then make all of your pull requests from `pr-` branches. You would just need to add:

```
general:
  branches:
    only:
      - /pr-*/
```